# plotsymbol label

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm playing with core-plot to generate a scatter plot. I've added a plot symbol and want to add a label near every symbol.

I able to do that but want to change the position of this label. I can set the offset but it move the label only vertically, I need to move the label horizontally.

Any way to do that?

this picture shows what i'd like.
[screen shot](http://www.iimmgg.com/image/8d82df5306108a7007f4f76defeee4d0)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic labels will always appear above the point. You can create annotations to label your data points. For each label, use `CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation`, anchor it to the coordinates of the data point, and set the displacement and content anchor.

To put the labels to the right of the point, set the displacement to (x, 0) where x is the number of pixels between the label and the center of the data point. Set the content anchor to (0, 0.5).